# Calling sync_client.cpp

Tags: c++, boost

In C++, I'm trying to create a function that will correctly call the main function in sync_client.cpp (code is visible here) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/iostreams/http_client.cpp.  To make it easier, I tried changing int main(...) to int downloadc(...) and creating a new int main but I get errors.  How do I get it to work?

```
int main(){
downloadc{"www.boost.org","/LICENSE_1_0.txt");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but I get errors"...

Comment: Whenever you post a question about errors, you should always include the *complete* and *unedited* error output, together with the code that causes the errors (with the lines causing the errors marked).

Comment: However, using proper parentheses for the function call might be a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `downloadc` as if it was main, with an argc and an argv :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* args[3] = {argv[0],"www.boost.org","/LICENSE_1_0.txt"};
    downloadc(3,args);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EricMorse Feel free to accept the answer if that's all you need.